# Mysql using temporary

Tags: mysql, using, temporary

My query uses a temporary table, which I'm doing wrong, can someone tell me?

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT t.city_id FROM (SELECT city_id FROM `geo__base` Where country = 'DE')as t


id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  geo__base   ref     country     country     8   const   43460   Using index condition; Using where; Using temporar...
```

Thanks all

Comment: There's no need for the subquery. Just do `select distinct city_id from geo_base where...`. That said, a temporary table isn't necessarily bad. It's a table in memory. Only when it says `temporary table on disk` it gets bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city_id FROM (SELECT city_id FROM geo_base WHERE country = 'DE') tmp;
```

Or as fancyPants commented above, just use this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT city_id FROM geo_base;
```